# Simple Injector Verify() in production code

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Is it best practise to call `container.Verify()` in production code?  I was thinking of moving to a:

```
#IF Debug
    container.Verify();
#ENDIF
```

I don't have any real reason to make the change, just curious as to what the general consensus/best practise is.

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not it is useful to call `Verify` is open for debate. Back in 2011, [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) did think [such a method is close to worthless](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/). My opinion is that that there is real value in calling `Verify`, but I understand Mark's sentiment and agree that calling `Verify` by itself is typically not enough. That's why there's clear guidance on [Verifying the container’s configuration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration) in the Simple Injector wiki about keeping your DI configuration verifiable.

With Simple Injector however, `Verify` does much more than testing whether it can create your object graphs. A call to `Verify` will kick-off Simple Injector's [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) which search for very common, but sometimes very hard to spot configuration errors (a feature which was not available during the time that Mark wrote that article).

In general my advice is to call `container.Verify` in your production code, for as long as feasible. Call it always at start-up, both in debug and release builds, in your staging environment and on production.

As the application gets bigger, it becomes more time consuming to call `container.Verify` during start-up. Some types of applications are more sensitive to this than others. For server applications it is usually okay to have a longer start-up time, while desktop and mobile phone applications must start more quickly.

Once you get into the position that a call to `Verify` takes too much time -but only then- you should remove the call to `Verify`, but at least still have a unit/integration test that calls `container.Verify`. I see no problem wrapping `Verify` in compiler directives (as you did in your question), but again note that IMO you should postpone the removal of a call to `Verify` in your startup path for as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steven.  If I was to do the above, I had planned on keeping it around for integration/unit tests, so that it would be guaranteed to run pre-deployment in some form.